# Filter rows of query based on group role in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT id, type, name
FROM users
```

This gives the result:

```
1  member jack
2  member sarah
3  manager ron
```

I want to modify the query that `type` `manager` will be shown only to users that has `hr` role.

Basically hr user should see:

```
1  member  jack
2  member  sarah
3  manager ron
```

non hr user should see

```
1  member  jack
2  member  sarah
```

I have a boolean query which gives the true false value if user has hr role or not:

```
select pg_has_role("current_user"(), 'hr'::name, 'MEMBER'::text)
```

but i cant seem to integrate it to the select query in order to filter the rows correctly.

I'm trying something like

```
SELECT id,type,name
FROM users
WHERE case when select pg_has_role("current_user"(), 'hr'::name, 
'MEMBER'::text) then ___________ else    _______________ end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following query (you don't need select when using pg_has_role inside WHERE)

```
select id,type,name
from users
WHERE type NOT IN (
     CASE WHEN pg_has_role("current_user"(), 'hr'::name, 'MEMBER'::text) 
     THEN '' 
     ELSE 'manager' END)
```